# Bluebird promise and no method 'reject'

Tags: mongoose, promise, bluebird

I've promisified Mongoose with Bluebird. This code worked using mPromise but now yields the error:

```
Object [object Promise] has no method 'reject'
```

The code:

```
var p = Order.findOneAsync(q).then(function(order) {
  return p.reject(Boom.badRequest());
```

This is overly simplified but the basics are there. How would I reject the promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw the error inside the handler:

```
var p = Order.findOneAsync(q).then(function(order) {
  throw Boom.badRequest();
});
```

Comment: K. Why would the reject fail though? Seems to be a documented method.

Comment: This appears to not cascade down and ends up as an unhandled exception dumped to my log by Bluebird.

Comment: Ah I see - I mistakenly assumed that bluebird done() was the equivalent of mPromise end() - evidently it is not.

Comment: @Yashua what is `end()`? Sounds useless. `Promise.reject()` is a static method, there is no such method documented as `.reject()`

Comment: In Hapi controllers I use reply for both result and errors. With mpromise I can do `myPromiseMethod().then(reply).end(reply)`. I think the equivalent with BB is `myPromiseMethod().then(reply).catch(reply)`. If I don't catch/end the error then it just becomes unhandled